# Getting MSB of a 32bit integer in MIPS, and merging it into the LSB of another value

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips

Is there any way to find the MSB of a 32bit integer in MIPS and then replace that to the LSB of another integer?

To elaborate, suppose A = 1000 and B = 1001  (4-bit examples to keep it short.)

I need to get the MSB of B ie 1 and swap this with the LSB of A.
Now A should become 1001.

Comment: The MSB of 1001 is 1?! What is your definition of "MSB"? Are these numbers binary? Even so, the MSB of 1001 is 1 only on a 4-bit architecture.

Comment: You should look up "conditional branches" in your MIPS textbook, and use one or more conditional branches to select what code to execute.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Integer 1 -> $a0
# Integer 2 -> $a1
# Result -> $a3

# Moving MSB to LSB, shifting in zeros
srl     $t1, $a0, 31

# Applying r = a ^ ((a ^ b) & mask)
# a = $a1
# b = $t1 = $a0 >> 31
xor     $t2, $a1, $t1
andi    $t2, $t2, 1          # mask=1 - keep only the low bit
xor     $a3, $a1, $t2
```

Assembly is fun!

Comment: A nice branch-less solution. (You don't need to do the XOR before the LI. LI is a synthetic instruction that causes the assembler to emit code that clears the destination register as necessary. Also the code before the SRL is not needed - there's no need to clear bits that are going to be shifted away.)

Comment: In my experience, you do need the XOR. AFAIK LI does not clear the register. For example, if I do LUI and then LI, register is not cleared and upper half-word maintains the value (thanks MIPS God...). And yes, you're right, the AND mask is not useful, I didn't notice, but anyway, it shows how to set up and use an AND mask. Also, having programmed assembly quite a bit, I prefer being sure the register is cleared because chasing such bugs is a damn headache ;)

Comment: I was looking for this exact process on google. Thanks for the help!

Comment: LUI doesn't merge into the old value, it replaces the whole register.  That's why `li` and `la` can be implemented as `lui` / `ori` or `lui` / `addiu` without having to know the old value of the low half.  https://godbolt.org/z/8zrjePzM4 shows that compilers can just use `lui` to implement `return 0x80000000` and `move $v0, $zero` to return 0.

Comment: Plus, if you did want to zero a register, you'd copy from `$zero` (like `ori $t0, $zero, 0`), not read the old value.  xor-zeroing is only special-cased by CPU hardware on x86; on ISAs like MIPS it's required to have a false dependency to implement memory dependency-ordering semantics  (the feature C++11 `memory_order_consume` was intended to expose).  And there's no saving in code-size; all MIPS instructions are 32 bits wide.  (Or with MIPS16 compressed instructions, 16-bits, in which case I'm not sure what the ideal zeroing instruction is, but it likely won't read the old value.)

Comment: More than half the instructions in your original version were unnecessary. (I fixed that in an edit).  `srl` shifts in zeros so you didn't need to isolate the MSB before shifting anyway.  Unfortunately MIPS can't do `x & -2` with a single ANDI instruction (it zero-extends immediates for bitwise boolean instructions, unlike other instructions), otherwise you could clear the LSB of one input, shift the other, and simply OR in the new LSB.  Constructing a `0xfffffffe` constant with `addiu $t2, $zero, -2` would let you still use 4 instructions though, with a shorter critical path latency.